# How to implement CanActivate guard in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement "CanActivate" method in my service, and below is the
service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class GuardUserSearchService implements CanActivate {

    CanActivate() {
        console.log('dummy guard clause for User search');
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I compile this typeScript code , it is displays following error

> Class 'GuardUserSearchService' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.

Any idea what is the issue in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Service must implement this function to fully implement that `CanActivate` interface:

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean { }
```

Note that the interface name is `CanActivate` (with uppercase `C`) while method's name is `canActivate` (lowercase `c`).

Comment: even after modification , it shows the same error. My angular2 version is RC-6.

Comment: Please check case-sensitivity too. The function should be `canActivate`, not `CanActivate`

Comment: lol..i was also doing the same mistake of upperCase 'C' in canActivate function..

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html), the interface looks like this:

```
interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean
}
```

So, your implementation is missing the arguments:

```
export class GuardUserSearchService implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        console.log('dummy guard clause for User search');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just one change required-

```
#both C&A is capital
export class Guard implements CanActivate () {
-code-
}

#here only A is in capital dont follow CammelCase
canActivate(){ 
-code
});
```